# Why does this .bat program recognize a path as existing when it doesn't?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-office, exists, not-exists

not my code just something I've been assigned to figure out/fix.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE` does not exist- I've checked hidden files as well. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office` exists, but not `root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE`. Yet, the program still jumps to `LOADITUP` instead of `LOADITUP2`

```
if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE GOTO LOADITUP
if not exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE GOTO LOADITUP2

:LOADITUP
echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "c:\la20aps\%1\fbLA20APS.accdb" /runtime /cmd %1 >startup.bat
start "closeme" startup
goto END

:LOADITUP2
echo "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "c:\la20aps\%1\fbLA20APS.accdb" /runtime /cmd %1 >startup-new32.bat
start "closeme" startup-new32
goto END

:END
exit
pause
```

Comment: You need to "quote the filename" if it contains spaces.

Comment: Per usual, something I spend too much time on thinking of complex solutions has actually a very simple answer. That seems to be working now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On executing

```
if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE GOTO LOADITUP
```

batch finds `C:\Program` does not exist, so ignore

Then it tries

```
if not exist C:\Program
```

which, indeed does not exist, so it attempts to execute

```
Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE GOTO LOADITUP2
```

which does not exist, so it proceeds to the next instruction, which is the `:LOADITUP` routine.

If you run from a "shortcut" error messages will not be visible (they appear, but the batch continues and wipes them out). You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.